# Problem with callback function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, callback, drop-down-menu

I am using the following functions to populate the dropmenu menu, my problem is that my click event is not firing ,and i am not able to populate the dynamic dropdown menu.

This is my Jquery function

```
function testXmlMenu() {
                getmenu(function (results) {
                 $("div[id ^= 'menuItemGroup']").slideUp(500);
                $.ajax(
                    {
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "JsonWebService.asmx/GetMenuItems",
                        data: '{"menuId":"' + results.data.MenuId + '"}',
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "xml",
                        success: function (items) {
                            $(event.target).children().remove();
                            var html = "<div id='menuItemGroup" + event.data.MenuId + "' style='display:none'>";
                            for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
                                html += "<div id='MenuItems'> <a href='" + items[j].NavigateUrl + "'>" +
                                items[j].Text + "</a></div>";
                            }
                            html += "</div>";
                            $(event.target).append(html);
                            $("#menuItemGroup" + event.data.MenuId).slideDown(500);
                        },
                        error: function (err) {
                            alert(err.status + " - " + err.statusText);
                        }
                    });







            });
    }
    function getmenu(callback)
     {
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "JsonWebService.asmx/GetMenus",
             data: "{}",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "xml",

             success:

                 function (results) {

                     $(results).find("Menu").each(function () {
                         var Text = $(this).find("Text").text();
                         var MenuId = $(this).find("MenuId").text();
                         alert(MenuId);
                         var dmenu = $("#Menudiv");
                         dmenu.append("<td><ul>"+Text+"</ul></td>");
                         $("dmenu.td").click(callback(results));


                     });


                 }
         });

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply can i give callback function name as getmenu, if so doesn't it enter into loop.

Comment: you can give it any name and yes by giving the name getmenu it will cause recursion if you dont want the recursive behavior then  create another handler to handle the click event

Answer (score 2):

I think your jQuery selector is switched around for your click action.

It should be:

```
$("td.dmenu").click(callback(results));
```